# Golang sql.RawBytes values being overridden on top of each other during scan loop

Tags: sql, go

I'm trying to query a database and storing all the results (`[]sql.RawBytes`) in a `[][]sql.RawBytes`. The problem I'm having is sometimes I'll have 2 results that end up overlapping with each other. For example if I have result1 `aaaaa` and result2 `bbbbbbbbbb` then sometimes I'll get the result `aaaaabbbbb` where result1 seemingly is transposed on top of result2.

This is what I currently have so far. I tried tweaking it and stepping through each loop but I can't figure out the pattern for when this occurs. Any help would be appreciated.

```golang
import (
   "database/sql"
   _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
)

func fetchRawResults(rows *sql.Rows, numColumns int) ([][]sql.RawBytes, error) {
   results := make([][]sql.RawBytes, 0)

   dest := make([]interface{}, numColumns)
   rawResult := make([]sql.RawBytes, numColumns)
   for i, _ := range dest {
      dest[i] = &rawResult[i]
   }

   for rows.Next() {
      err := rows.Scan(dest...)
      if err != nil {
         log.Fatal(err)
      }

      currentResult := make([]sql.RawBytes, len(rawResult))
      copy(currentResult, rawResult)

      results = append(results, currentResult)
   }

   rows.Close() // manually closing the query here, but the close is also deferred by the caller
   return results, nil
}
```

Comment: You are reusing `dest` for every `rows.Next()`; that *is* the problem, don't do that. Try this https://go.dev/play/p/XYE9kwoJPe_p to see if my guess is correct.

Comment: You can also work around the problem by "resetting" the pointed to raw bytes after the `copy`, i.e. https://go.dev/play/p/urgbh5SQk6T

Comment: @mkopriva thank you, I went with the first approach. That seems to have fixed the issue for the most part. I'm running into issues with differentiating between `NULL` and `""` now.